# How provide results based on the query results in a url?

Tags: javascript

Is there a javascript solution to read the url,create a string from it, and build a if statement based on the results?  Does anyone know of a tutorial or can provide me with some tips of how to accomplish this.

To be more specific I am trying to do this based on a search result.  So.. for example the url is something like:

http://www.site.com/catalogsearch/result?q=asdf&kw=asdf&x=0&y=0

and working off of Daniels response I am trying this with no luck:

```
if (window.location.search ==='?q=asdf') {
alert("You searched for asdf");
}
```

Comment: Can you ... be more specific?  Expected input/output?  Intentions?  Anything you've tried?

Comment: I am trying to come up with something using Daniels answer but no luck yet.  Specifically I am trying to write a conditional statement based on the results from the search property.

Comment: function getUrlParam(param)
{
  param = param.replace(/([\[\](){}*?+^$.\\|])/g, "\\$1");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + param + "=([^&#]*)");
  var url   = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
  var match = regex.exec(url);
  return match ? match[1] : "";
}

var param = getUrlParam("q");

if (param == "asdf") {
alert(param); 
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the URL, or parts for it, using the [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object.

For example, consider the following URL:

> #### http://www.google.com:80/search?q=devmo#test

These are the standard properties of the `window.location` object, and the value you would get for the above URL:

```
property   | value
-----------+-----------------------------------------------------
hash       | #test
host       | www.google.com:80
hostname   | www.google.com
href       | http://www.google.com:80/search?q=devmo#test
pathname   | /search
port       | 80
protocol   | http:
search     | ?q=devmo
```

For example, if you want to check the pathname, you could do the following:

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/search') {
   // do something
}
```

Comment: +1, but I would recommend not using the path `/search` in the example url as it was ambiguous with the property 'search'.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
var str = window.location.href; 
if(str.indexOf("http") > - 1){
 //ah an if statment!
alert("url has http");
}
```