# I can't get value in URL | PHP

Tags: php

URL ex: `gamob.net/token?#access_token=EAAKJnZAm`

Code PHP:
eg 1:

```
$token = $_GET['access_token'];
echo $token;
```

eg 2:

```
$token = $_GET['#access_token'];
echo $token;
```

eg 3:

```
$token =  $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
echo $token;
```

All can't get value in Url. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable # can only be retrieved by Javascript.

Look this exemple: [how to save facebook access token after success](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10440299/8418326)

Comment: Oh haha! Thank you. Yes, I need it

Answer (score 4):

I think the char `#` is reserved to mark anchor.

I have never seen it in GET parameters

try this ex url : `gamob.net/token?access_token=EAAKJnZAm`

And acces the param like that : `$_GET['access_token'];`

Also `?`is to mark the beginning of the params and & separation between parametres

Comment: I want get token facebook. But i can't get value because char "#".

Comment: The value is not the problem, it's the param name that the problem, if you can try renaming the param, at least when you pass it in the URL

Comment: Thank you! I can't renaming the param. 
Facebook response Url.